# Rendering a menu in vue 3 after ajax method

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I've gotten this menu to work without filtering it, but now I'm doing an ajax request to filter out menu items the user isn't supposed to see, and I'm having some trouble to figure out how to set the resulting menu data, the line that is not working is commented below:

```
<script>
   import { ref } from 'vue';
   import axios from 'axios';

   var currentSelected = 'device_access';

   var menuData = [
   { 
      text: 'Device Access', 
      id: 'device_access',
      children: [
      { 
        text: 'Interactive',
        link: '/connection_center'
      },{ 
        text: 'Reservation',
        link: '/reserve_probe'
      }, { 
        text: 'Reservation Vue',
        link: '/reservation.html'
      }
    ]
  }, {
    text: 'Automation',
    id: 'automation',
    show: ['is_mxadmin', 'can_schedule_scripts'],
    children: [
      { 
        text: 'Builder',
        link: '/builder', 
      },{
        text: 'Execution Results',
        link: '/test_suite_execution_results'
      },
    ]
  }
];

function hasMatch(props, list) {
  var match = false;
  for (var i=0; i < list.length && !match; i++) {
    match = props[list[i]];
  }
  return match;
}

export default {
  name: 'Header',
  setup() {

    const cursorPosition = ref('0px');
    const cursorWidth = ref('0px');
    const cursorVisible = ref('visible');

    //the menu is zero length until I get the data:
    const menu = ref([]);

    return {
      menu,
      cursorPosition,
      cursorWidth,
      cursorVisible
    }
  },

  created() {
     let that = this;

    axios.get('navigation_props')
      .then(function(res) {
        var data = res.data;
        var result = [];
        menuData.forEach(function(item) {
          if (!item.show || hasMatch(data, item.show)) {
            var children = [];
        
            item.children.forEach(function (child) {
              if (!child.show || hasMatch(data, child.show)) {
                children.push({ text: child.text, link: child.link });
              }
            });
       
           if (children.length > 0) {
              result.push({ text: item.text, 
                children: children, lengthClass: "length_" + children.length });
            }
        }
    }); 
    //continues after comment
```

this is probably the only thing wrong, I've run this in the debugger and I'm getting the
correct data:

```
    that.$refs.menu = result;
```

since the menu is not being rebuilt, then this fails:

```
    //this.restoreCursor();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
     // Manage errors if found any
  });
},
```

Comment: It's because the menu is blank, so the object it is trying to position the cursor next to doesn't exist.

I have tried 20 other things and I just don't have a handle on how to do this with ref or reactive. All the examples I have found have only one data item, I have four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`this.$refs`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-properties.html#refs) is for [template refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html), which are not the same as the [`ref`s](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#refs) from `setup()`.

And the data fetching in `created()` should probably be moved to `onMounted()` in `setup()`, where the `axios.get()` callback sets `menu.value` with the results:

```js
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const menu = ref([])
    
    onMounted(() => {
      axios.get(/*...*/).then(res => {
        const results = /* massage res.data */

        menu.value = results
      })
    })

    return {
      menu
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem.

This code above will probably work with:

```
that.menu = result;
```

You don't need: that.$refs.menu

You can't do it in setup because for some reason "that" is not yet defined.

In my working code I added a new method:

```
methods: {
   setMenuData: function() {
     this.menu = filterMenu();
   },
}
```

And "this" is properly defined inside them.